# NestJS: If I want to activate service B from service A should I do this directly or call on Controller B?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Hi I'm finishing up my first api CRUD so not sure regarding this one aspect of it.

If I have the following:

Controller A
Service A

Controller B
Service B

I want to activate a function in Service B. Should I call an HTTP request to Controller B?

HTTP request would also add in a DTO (Not sure if another DTO is needed if I'm calling it directly from services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service should not be tied to Controller but a business logic instead.

You can call the Service B directly from service A